# How to display an image captured with cordova-plugin-media-capture

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-camera, cordova-plugins, filereader

I am using [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media-capture) which has allowed me to capture an image with my Android phone.

Now how am I supposed to display the image just captured in my app? The following didn't work. It said: ***"TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."***

```
function capturePhoto(){
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(
        file=>{
            getBase64(file).then(b64=>{
                document.getElementById('fsPhotoI').src=b64;
            }).catch(e=>alert(e));
        },
        error=>{alert(error);},
        {limit:1}
    );
}

function getBase64(f) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
function capturePhoto(){
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(
        file=>{
            document.getElementById('fsPhotoI').src=file[0].fullPath;
        },
        e=>{alert(JSON.stringify(e));},
        {limit:1}
    );
}
```

One thing I overlooked was that the 'file' variable returned is an array instead of a single file, even when only one image is captured.